# hiding unordered list items in jquery a tag click

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list that renders as shown;

```
<div id="day4">
    <span id="lblDay4" class="calendartilelabel">10/11/2013</span>
    <hr class="calendartileline" />
    <ul id="day4List" class="calendartile">
    <li>Nov Sugar Options Expiration</li>
    <li>Nov Coffee Options Expiration</li>
    <li class='next'><a href='#'>Next--></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide the currently displayed ul but cannot retrieve the id of the ul to do so.
I was using the function

```
 $("ul.calendartile > li > a").on("click", function (event) {
       var clickedUl = event.target.id;                    
       $(clickedUl).hide();                 
  });
```

The problem there is that it hides all the unordered lists with the class calendartile, therefore I need to retrieve the id of the UL tag whose a tag was clicked. I tried using the following which I thought made sense

```
 $("ul.calendartile > li > a").on("click", function (event) {
       var clickedUl = event.parent().parent().target.id;   
       alert(clickedUl);                 
       $(clickedUl).hide();                 
  });
```

But the alert is blank, ie not finding the id. How do I find the id of the ul tag under which its listitem a tag click was fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$("ul.calendartile > li > a").on("click", function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var clickedUl = $(this).closest('ul').prop('id');   
       $('#' + clickedUl).hide();                 
 });
```

`event` doesn't have a parent(). event is not an element also parent() is a function on jquery object , you can always use `this` context to get the clicked element and navigate to its parent using `closest()`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVz2q/)**

I would be surpised if you get an alert at all. because you must be seeing an error in your console.

Comment: works as expected, much appreciated. I will mark as answer in 8 min